# C++ Type Identifier

Tags: c++, c++11

Okay, so, if I do this in a C++ header function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// Prerequisites ^
int main(){
    int io_print([Here's what I need help with]){};
};
```

I know the code example was completely syntax wrong, but what I need help with is trying to use a type which allows integer, float and string.
So I can simply do io_print(40) and io_print("Hi").
I've tried this and simply can't find any type that allows this, if anyone by any chance knows the answer then please reply.

I'm doing this as I want to redefine functions. Please don't ask why.

Comment: Never write `using namespace std;` at global scope in a header.

Comment: C++ is strongly typed, so this is not a typical way of approaching things.  What you can do instead is provide a templated approach, see @Brian, or you can have polymorphic functions (they take different parameter signatures, accomodating the types that you want).  You're approach is is the kind of approach for languages with dynamic typing.

Comment: @Brian why not write the `using namespace std` at the global scope?

Comment: @Golazo I just said don't do it in headers. Because if you do it in a header, then it imports everything from `namespace std` into the global scope for everyone who includes the header. It's sometimes fine to do it in a file that won't be included by any other files.

Comment: @Golazo:  naming conflicts.  If I define my own `sqrt` function, I can separate them by using `std::sqrt`.  If I have `using namespace std;` the compiler (and readers) will be confused with the two versions of `sqrt`.  If you must, a preferred practice is to use `using std::cout;`, i.e. state the individual `std` functions that you are using.

Answer (score 6):

```
template <typename T>
void io_print(const T& x) {
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: This is, of course, assuming that the steps taken to print are generic that way. If not, simple method [overloading](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm) will be fine.